# Rails ActionMailer: Send email only if @user has is_admin also

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I have this set up for sending an email to a new user after they register. Right now it sends an email to ANY new user.

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def welcome_email(user)
  @user = user
  mail(to: @user.email,
       from: "Thinkrtc",
       subject: "Welcome To Thinkrtc"
    )
  end
end
```

I also have a second way a user can sign up, which has a is_admin boolean. So, when they sign up in the second way, they get the is_admin is true boolean.

I want to set up my UserMailer up there to only send it to the people who creates a new account on the second way and gets the is_admin = "true".

Comment: `is_admin` is a model attribute? if so, you can put a `return unless @user.is_admin` at the top. But I think I didn't understood correctly...

Comment: @mrlew It's in the scheme: http://image.prntscr.com/image/301a780f7b454277a8453783b1f36d6b.png

Comment: If you want to bypass email sending you should simply return the method, like I said before. Is that it? Or I misunderstood?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def welcome_email(user)
    @user = user 
    if @user.is_admin
      mail(to: @user.email,
         from: "Thinkrtc",
         subject: "Welcome To Thinkrtc"
      )
    end
  end
end
```

This will send an email if the user has is_admin == true.